# What is the formula for angular momentum in four dimensional formalism of General Relativity?

Tags: angular-momentum

Might it be $L^{\nu}=(0, \vec L)$, where $\vec L=\int\,\vec p \times \vec r\,dV$ is the three dimensional angular momentum? But latter would hold only for low angular velocities. What is the angular momentum vector in Special Relativity? We must use the four dimensional vectors. But the product $\epsilon_{\nu \mu \alpha \beta}\,p^{\alpha}\,x^{\beta}$ is not a vector, but the tensor.

Comment: Have you looked at [the Wikipedia article on relativistic angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_angular_momentum)?

Comment: No, I was sure that nobody knows. But thank you.